# When to use which()?

Tags: r

It seems like the `which()` function is a little redundant, since you can already subset a data.frame like this:

```
data1[data1$foo>0,]
```

without using `which()`.

When is it *necessary* to subset with `which()`?

Comment: Sometimes the value of the index is important. For example, you want the row *after* or *before* some event. In such cases, using `which` can be handy because you can add or subtract 1 or even do both to get the surrounding rows. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961021/data-table-cutoff-row-after-duplicate) for a second example.

Comment: Basically: whenever you need to know which elements of a logical vector are TRUE.

Comment: You are entirely correct: `which` is very rarely necessary or useful. There are some exceptions but these are much fewer than many people realise.

Comment: I use `which` very often. You use `which` when you want indices meeting certain criteria but you don't want the data itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference appears when there are NA values:

```
dd <- data.frame(a = c(-1, NA, 1), b = 2)
ok <- dd$a > 0

dd[which(ok),]
##   a b
## 3 1 2

dd[ok, ]
##     a  b
## NA NA NA
## 3   1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

`data1[data1$foo>0,]` this give back you Boolean value :

Like `T F T F`

Also, recommend subset , `subset(data1,foo>0)` when you have `NA`

---

`data1[which(data1$foo>0),]` give back the position of `T`

Like `1,3`

Comment: I don’t think this is answering the question.